# Using trained keras model in google ml-engine

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to use gcloud ml-engine with tensorflow, more precisely I would like to use an already trained keras model.

I managed to do this with a sciktlearn model but this not the same here...

First i train a simple model with Keras

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

# Creating the dataset
X = np.random.random((500,9))
y = (np.random.random(500)>0.5).astype(int)

# Splitting 
idx_train, idx_test = np.arange(400), np.arange(400,500)
X_train, X_test = X[idx_train], X[idx_test]
y_train, y_test = y[idx_train], y[idx_test]



def define_model():    
    input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(9,),name="values")
    hidden = keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', name="hidden")(input1)

    preds = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="labels")(hidden)

    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input1, 
                  outputs=preds)

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam', 
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.summary()

    return model

model = define_model()
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=10, 
          epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

I read i need a SavedModel to use it in ml-engine here https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models

It seems I have to transform it to an estimator

```
model.save("./model_trained_test.h5")
estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model_path="./model_trained_test.h5")
```

I manage to make prediction with this estimator

```
def input_function(features,labels=None,shuffle=False):
    input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"values": features},
        y=labels,
        shuffle=shuffle
    )
    return input_fn
score = estimator_model.evaluate(input_function(X_test, labels=y_test.reshape(-1,1)))
```

In order to export it to a SavedModel I need a serving_input_receiver_fn. I did not find on the internet an example of my situation, which seemed simple to me, so I tried this function and then I saved the model in the "here_are_estimators" folder

```
feature_spec = {'values': tf.FixedLenFeature(9, dtype=tf.float32)}

def serving_input_receiver_fn():

    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                           shape=[None],
                                           name='input_tensors')
    receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
    features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

estimator_model.export_savedmodel("./here_are_estimators",
                                  serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

my input.json looks like this

```
{"examples":[{"values":[[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.9,1.5,1.6,7.3,1.5]]}]}
```

I uploaded the content of the generated file, a variables folder and a saved_model.pb file to GCS in the directory DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE

When I try to run a local prediction with gcloud with this command:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir $DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE --json-instances="input.json" --verbosity debug --framework tensorflow
```

I have this error

```
cloud.ml.prediction.prediction_utils.PredictionError: Failed to run the provided model: Exception during running the graph: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1) for Tensor 'input_tensors:0', which has shape '(?,)' (Error code: 2)
```

I guess something is wrong with my input.json or the serving_input_receiver_fn, or both ?, but I cant find out what. If someone can tell me what is wrong it will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to parse tf.Example since you are sending JSON. Try this for the export:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn(): 
    inputs = {"values": tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,
                                       shape=[None, 9],
                                       name='input_tensors')}
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs) 

estimator_model.export_savedmodel("./here_are_estimators", serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

The input should look like:

```
{"values":[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.9,1.5,1.6,7.3,1.5]}
```

There's also a more concise "shorthand":

```
[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.9,1.5,1.6,7.3,1.5]
```

Comment: thank you for your help ! This works but the actual input should be: [0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.9,1.5,1.6,7.3,1.5] .
 Maybe you could edit your answer for the future readers.

Comment: @LouisDacquet: Are you referring to the shortand or the "values" dict? I updated values dict which was definitely wrong, but I *think* the shorthand is right (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Thx, however this is the same for the shorthand the correct value is [0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.9,1.5,1.6,7.3,1.5]